# Javascript, Can't find the error

Tags: javascript

I somehow am not able to find what is wrong with the following code. It's a javascript code and it never execute `if ( gender === 'undefined' || gender === '' )` even if gender is 'undefined' even though `else if ( portfolioFile === 'undefined' || portfolioFile === '' )` is working as it should be.

```
var portfolioFile = $ ( '#user_file' ).val (  );

var gender = $ ( 'input[name=gender_group]:checked', '#sign_up' ).val (  );

alert ( gender );

if ( gender === 'undefined' || gender === '' ){
    alert ( 'if' );
    return;
}
else if ( portfolioFile === 'undefined' || portfolioFile === '' ){
    alert ('else if');
    return;
}
else{
    alert ('else');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the variable is `'undefined'` and not `undefined`? There's a difference...

Comment: I flagged this as being off-topic > asking for debugging help. It does not appear as if you are debugging yourself (`console.log()`, for example). Please post what you have done so far to correct the issue. What is the expected behavior (both high and lower level)?

Comment: @HunterStevens You did see the `alert()`, right?

Comment: @Juhana The problem is one of the condition is working with the same syntax but other is not. On the other hand let me give undefined a try and update.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, it would help to see the actual HTML involved. Otherwise, we're diagnosing a problem we can only guess at.

Comment: @StudentX That's probably because your selector is wrong. You'll have to show the relevant HTML. `.val()` will *never* return the string "undefined" unless that's the actual value of the input field, i.e. if the user has literally typed "undefined" in a text input for example.

Comment: @Juhana Well, the undefined did solve the problem. Didn't know that, thanks. But why the 'else if' worked? in both the cases the val() won't be returning string "undefined"..

Comment: @StudentX perhaps `portfolioFile` actually does contain `''`

Comment: @PaulRoub That makes sense. I was only concentrating on undefined/'undefined' :(

Answer (score 2):

You mean `typeof gender === 'undefined'` etc.